# DevExpress ASP.NET TextBox Number or Character validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

When using masking on the textbox, I need to enter a hyphen in credit card format. But since I only checked for numbers, I guess the validation does not accept dashes. Thanks for your help.

```
<script>
   function fn_AllowonlyNumeric(s, e) {
       var theEvent = e.htmlEvent || window.event;
       var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
       key = String.fromCharCode(key);
       var regex = /[0-9]/;
       if (!regex.test(key)) {
           theEvent.returnValue = false;
           if (theEvent.preventDefault)
               theEvent.preventDefault();
       }
   }
</script>
```

```
<dx:BootstrapTextBox AutoPostBack="true" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ClientInstanceName="ttxtSozNo" ID="KartNumarasi" MaxLength="19" runat="server" CssClasses-Input="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false" OnTextChanged="KartNumarasi_TextChanged" >
<ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s,e){ fn_AllowonlyNumeric(s,e);}" />
<CssClasses Input="form-control valid" />
<ValidationSettings ErrorText="" RequiredField-IsRequired="True" SetFocusOnError="True" RegularExpression-ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{6,16}$">
<RegularExpression ErrorText="" />
<RequiredField ErrorText="" IsRequired="True" />
</ValidationSettings>
<MaskSettings Mask="0000-0000-0000-0000" />
</dx:BootstrapTextBox>
```

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: Why don't you contact the DevExpress Support?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you do not need the client-side javascript validation code/handler, which contradicts the declarative mask settings, at all:

```
<dx:BootstrapTextBox ...>
   <%--<ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s,e){ fn_AllowonlyNumeric(s,e);}" />--%>
    ...
    <MaskSettings Mask="0000-0000-0000-0000" />
</dx:BootstrapTextBox>
```

Check out the [related sample](https://demos.devexpress.com/Bootstrap/Editors/TextBox.aspx#Mask) - to see how it works.